# strcmp returns false for for equal char sequence

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-strings, strcmp

I have a function that use `strcmp` to make a decision, see below:

```
void get_data(file_observational_area * _file_observational_area, int dimensions, int * start_indices, int * end_indices) {
    char buffer[1024];
    FILE *file;
    size_t nread;

    if (NULL != _file_observational_area) {

        cout << "***_file_observational_area \n";

        if (NULL != _file_observational_area->_file) {
            //if the data is in a file 

            cout << "****_file_observational_area->_file \n";
            cout << "***_file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier:" << _file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier << "\n";
            cout << "***_file_observational_area->_file->file_name:" << _file_observational_area->_file->file_name << "\n";
            cout << "***data_file_local_identifier:" << data_file_local_identifier << "\n";

            if (strcmp(_file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier, data_file_local_identifier) == 1) {

                if (NULL != _file_observational_area->_file->file_name) {
                    //open the file 
                    file = fopen(_file_observational_area->_file->file_name, "r");
                    if (file) {
                        while ((nread = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof (buffer), file)) > 0)
                            cout << buffer << "\n";
                        if (ferror(file)) {
                            /* deal with error */
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                cout << "***_file_observational_area  NOT A file \n";
            }

            if (NULL != file) {
                fclose(file);
                file = NULL;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The data_file_local_identifier that is used for comparison is defined in struct:

```
#ifndef DATA_FILE__H
#define DATA_FILE__H
#define data_file_local_identifier "file"

struct data_file
{
    char * file_name;
    char * local_identifier;

};

typedef struct data_file data_file; 

#endif /* DATA_FILE__H */
```

**program output snippet:**

```
****_file_observational_area->_file 
***_file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier:file
***_file_observational_area->_file->file_name:A0087_0008_597249118_597252671_181130002623_eu.csv
***data_file_local_identifier:file
***_file_observational_area NOT A file
```

In the get_data function above this line of code:

```
      if (strcmp(_file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier, data_file_local_identifier) == 1)
```

Returns false instead of true, although if you look at output both string are "file". So why is this failing?

Comment: It looks like both of your strings have the value `file`. If the strings are the same, `strcmp` should return `0` (read more here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp). Why do you expect the value to be `1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to assume that `strcmp` returns 1 if strings are equal.

But `strcmp` returns [0 if strings are equal, or a number whose sign represents which is "smaller"](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

> Returns an integral value indicating the relationship between the strings:
>
> <0 the first character that does not match has a lower value in ptr1 than in ptr2
>
> 0 the contents of both strings are equal
>
> >0 the first character that does not match has a greater value in ptr1 than in ptr2

Comment: That is the common sense, I've been noticing that the return values are really -1 0 and 1 in several compiles I'v tested see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Xyo8-n) an example

Comment: You don’t have an engineering right to assume it will always be the case. You cannot prove the nonexistence of a platform that differs.

Comment: I'm not assuming anything, I was trying to discuss the result of some experiments, looks like I chose the wrong person to do it with.

Comment: That is good advice I'll do that.

Answer (score 3):

[`strcmp`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) returns `0` when the strings are equal, and a non-zero values when they are not.

To check for equality, use

```
if (strcmp(a, b) == 0) {
```

Answer (score 2):

From the C Standard (7.23.4.2 The strcmp function)

> 3 **The strcmp function returns an integer** greater than, **equal to**, or
>   less than **zero**, accordingly **as the string pointed to by s1 is** greater
>   than, **equal to**, or less than **the string pointed to by s2**.

So if you want to check whether two strings are equal each other then you should write

```
if ( strcmp( s1, s2 ) == 0 )
{
    // ...
}
```

Or alternatively

```
if ( !strcmp( s1, s2 ) )
{
    // ...
}
```

though such a condition can confuse readers.

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the strcmp documentation, you can see that the return value for this function.

I believe you should compare with 0 to test equal string.  >0 and <0 mean different things.

change '== 1' to '== 0'

strcmp(_file_observational_area->_file->local_identifier, data_file_local_identifier) == 0

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/